# Saving and reading data from chrome extension in JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, storage, google-chrome-storage

Simple task. User can enter their login to form inside of google chrome extension, click button - login, and I should save this login into storage. Next time, when user will open extension- login should appear in the input. User can change it by entering new login end click button. The problem is that getChanges does not receive anything.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>      
        <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>      
        <input type="text" id="login" placeholder="login">
        <button id="doLogin">Login</button>          
        <script src="popup.js"></script>  
    </body>
</html>
```

popup.js:

```
document.getElementById("doLogin").addEventListener("click", doLogin);

var extratedLogin= getChanges('myLogin');
$('#login').val(extratedLogin);

function getChanges(name) {  
    chrome.storage.local.get(name, function(result) {
      console.log('myLogin= '+JSON.stringify(result));
      return result.key;
    });
}

function saveChanges(name,value) {   
    chrome.storage.local.set({name: value}, function() { 
        console.log('Settings saved for '+ name);
    });
}
function doLogin(){
    //do something
    saveChanges('myLogin', $('#login').val());
}
```

manifest.json :

```
"permissions": ["storage", ...]
```

Comment: the storage API is asynchronous so it doesn't return anything. You should use result.key inside the callback. Also it should be `result[name]`, not result.key. More info: [Returning Chrome storage API value without function](//stackoverflow.com/q/38425751)

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you for pointing it out. I've remove my comment.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you for the explanation. I changed to getChanges('myLogin'); and inside of chrome.storage.local.get - setting value to input. But it also does not work. I'm receiving 'undefined'  from result[name].

Comment: Ah, that's because your saveChanges is also incorrect, it should use `{[name]: value}`, more info: [How to use a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2274242)

Answer (score 1):

Was error is syntax. Here is right saving and loading

```
window.onload = function() {
        chrome.storage.local.get(['mylogin'], function(items) {
            console.log('Settings retrieved ', items);
            $('#login').val(items['mylogin']); 
        });
    }      

    function doLogin(){          
        chrome.storage.local.set({'mylogin': $('#login').val()}, function() { 
            console.log('Fields data was saved.');
        });
    }
```